# Converting function instr from Oracle to PostgreSQL (sql only)

Tags: postgresql, instr

I am working on converting something from Oracle to PostgreSQL. In the Oracle file there is a function:

```
instr(string,substring,starting point,nth location)
```

Example:
`instr(text, '$', 1, 3)`

In PostgreSQL this does not exist, so I looked up an equivalent function (4 parameter is important).

I found:
The function `strpos(str, sub)` in Postgres is equivalent of `instr(str, sub)` in Oracle. Tried options via split_part (it didn't work out).
I need the same result only with standard functions Postgres (not own function).
Maybe someone will offer options, even redundant in code.

Comment: position ( 'substring' IN substring ( 'string' FROM start FOR count))

Comment: Wrong result, I don't need the first occurrence (example 3)

Comment: what do you need ? true or false ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be done in pure SQL using `string_to_array`.

```sql
with tab(val) as (
  select 'qwe$rty$123$456$78'
  union all
  select 'qwe$rty$123$'
  union all
  select '123$456$'
  union all
  select '123$456'
)
select
  val
  /*Oracle's signature: instr(string , substring [, position [, occurrence ] ])*/
  , case
      when
        array_length(
          string_to_array(substr(val /*string*/, 1 /*position*/), '$' /*substring*/),
          1
        ) <= 3 /*occurrence*/
      then 0
      else
        length(array_to_string((
            string_to_array(substr(val /*string*/, 1 /*position*/), '$' /*substring*/)
          )[:3/*occurrence*/],
          '$'/*substring*/)
        ) + 1
  end as instr
from tab
```

| val | instr |
| --- | --- |
| qwe$rty$123$456$78 | 12 |
| qwe$rty$123$ | 12 |
| 123$456$ | 0 |
| 123$456 | 0 |

Postgres: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n1wju3W6)
Oracle: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tCzJrLH8)